# How to replace Android's default Notification/Status bar?

Tags: android

Is there a way to replace (or suppress and launch) with my own custom view or App?

Answer (score 0):

Sure go full screen. If you want an example just create new activity and select "fullScreenActivity" then you can view the style and code to own the full screen. However, you can remove the timer delay and animation and just force it right away.

I feel obligated to mention though that building your own status bar sounds wildly out of place. Are you sure you didn't mean the Actionbar? Either way, that is how you accomplish removing the status bar if that really is what you want to do.

For another example of how to do it in XML or Manifest you can see styles here:
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html